# Why is this regression plot only plotting 2 of my regression coefficients?

Tags: r, regression

```
#Plot voor price - carat
plot(training_diamanten$carat,training_diamanten$price, xlim=c(0,4.5),
+      ylim=c(0,20000), pch=1, las=1, bty='l', col='dark blue', 
+      xlab = 'Hoeveelheid karaat in gewicht',
+      ylab='De prijs in US dollars',
+      main = 'Hoeveelheid karaat in gewicht vs de prijs in US dollars')
abline(model_carat, col='red', lwd=5)

Warning message:
In abline(model_carat, col = "red", lwd = 5) :
  only using the first two of 263 regression coefficients
```

Comment: Where is `model_carat` defined? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's unclear how you would plot a line with more than 2 coefficients on a 2D plot.

Comment: I defined my model for carat with this formule: 

model_carat <- lm(price ~ carat, data = training_diamanten)
summary(model_carat)

Comment: It seems like `carat` is categorical, can you check its class? What is `class(training_diamanten$carat)`?

Comment: > class(training_diamanten$carat)
[1] "character"

Does it need to be a numeric?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I get when splitting the `diamonds` dataset 70:30:

Splitting in train and test dataset:

```
dt = sort(sample(nrow(diamonds), nrow(diamonds)*.7))

training_diamanten <- diamonds[dt,]
test_diamanten <- diamonds[dt,]
```

Your provided code:

```
model_carat <- lm(price ~ carat, data = training_diamanten) 

summary(model_carat) 

plot(training_diamanten$carat,training_diamanten$price, xlim=c(0,4.5),
     ylim=c(0,20000), pch=1, las=1, bty='l', col='dark blue',
     xlab = 'Hoeveelheid karaat in gewicht',
     ylab='De prijs in US dollars',
     main = 'Hoeveelheid karaat in gewicht vs de prijs in US dollars')
abline(model_carat, col='red', lwd=5)
```

[image]

Comment: I have run the exact code you provided @TarJae but I still get the same warning
Warning message:
In abline(model_carat, col = "red", lwd = 5) :
  only using the first two of 267 regression coefficients

Is it possible im just missing a package in R?

Comment: Hmmh. Try: `model_carat <- lm(price ~ as.numeric(as.character(carat)), data = training_diamanten) `